# Represent a route in er diagram that is dynamic

Tags: sql, database, database-design, architecture, entity-relationship

I have to implement a faculty system where if a faculty wants to apply for a leave, his leave application follows the path
Faculty -> HOD -> Dean -> Director
So, I have to store this route in an ER diagram but the catch is that this route can be changed anytime for example the new route may become
Faculty -> HOD -> Dean -> Staff -> Director
The admin will make such a change. Our system should be able to incorporate this change without having to recompile the entire database

I am thinking of making tables that somehow store their successor only. But how to do this in an er diagram.

Comment: Please read [ask] including re research effort. Give some design. What options did you find? Why can't you do what you would do for any other ER design with a relationship X(a,b)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: can you add more detail requirement?